# Implications of querying database before lambda_handler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Here is the pseudo-code for what current lambda function looks like;

```py
import pandas
import pymysql


def get_db_data(con_):
    query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    data = pandas.read_sql(query, con_)
    return data


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    con = pymysql.connect()
    data = get_db_data(con)
    """
    do other things with event
    """
    con.close()
```

I am debating if I can do this instead:

```py
import pandas
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect()


def get_db_data(con_):
    query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    data = pandas.read_sql(query, con_)
    return data


data = get_db_data(con)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    do other things with event
    """
    con.close()
```

But I am not sure if it is a good practice. What implications would the second option have on run-time and cost? Is it against the recommended way?

Comment: One consequence of the code you're considering using is that it will cache the value of `data` from the cold start invocation. For each subsequent warm invocation, it will not re-run the SQL query but will instead use the cached value of `data`, as the code is written currently. That might be a good thing or it might not, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a database connection in a Lambda function, it is best to follow [AWS best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html#function-code) and use INIT code (which is where you are almost heading) to load expensive resources.

> Take advantage of execution environment reuse to improve the performance of your function. Initialize SDK clients and database connections outside of the function handler, and cache static assets locally in the /tmp directory. Subsequent invocations processed by the same instance of your function can reuse these resources. This saves cost by reducing function run time.

Lambda can run from either a COLD or WARM start.  On COLD start, the code outside the lambda handler is executed.  When a Lambda is run from a WARM start, the resources loading during COLD start will be available.  By including resources like database connection opening in the COLD start, subsequent WARM starts will not have to re-execute the same expensive operation.  Getting to reuse the WARM start requires that calls to the specific Lambda be within a short period of time.  This can greatly reduce the execution time on your Lambda functions and this reduce costs!

Based on where you were going, I would say to rewrite it as such:

```
import pandas
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect()
 
def get_db_data(con_):
    query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    data = pandas.read_sql(query, con_)
    return data
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = get_db_data(con)
    """
    do other things with event
    """
    con.close()
```

This concept is also explained well in the AWS Lambda docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/static-initialization.html).

Also, consider what the duration of the connection is in its settings (client and server).  If the connection closes before the Lambda's instance goes away - you might want to include an isOpen check prior to using the connection and providing logic necessary to reopen it.

Comment: Sounds like `con.close()` can also be outside the `lambda_handler`, since `con` may not even be available for a warm start once it has been closed.

Comment: In this setup, there is no destructor so calling con.close() from outside the handler may close it after opening it.  When your Lambda 'instance' is destroyed, the connection should be closed as a consequence of going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, both approaches have their merits, and the choice depends on factors such as cold start time sensitivity, resource management, and the nature of your Lambda workload. To reuse connections, consider using connection pooling and ensuring proper scoping to mitigate potential issues.

**First Version (Connection Created Inside lambda_handler):**

- Pros:

  - Resource Management: Ensures proper closure of the database connection after each Lambda invocation.
  - Isolation: Each invocation gets a new connection, ensuring isolation.
  - Faster Cold Starts: This may result in faster cold starts if connection setup is a significant portion.
- Cons:

  - Overhead: Establishing a new connection may introduce some overhead.

**Second Version (Connection Created Outside lambda_handler):**

- Pros:

  - Reuse: Reuses the same connection, potentially reducing the overhead of connection setup.
- Cons:

  - Resource Leaks: Keep connection scope limited to Lambda execution; global connections can lead to resource leaks.
  - Concurrency Issues: Ensure thread safety if multiple invocations modify the same global connection.

**Recommendations:**

- Limited Connection Scope: If reusing connections, limit the connection scope to the Lambda execution.
- Use Connection Pooling: Consider using connection pooling for efficient connection management.
- Lambda Concurrency: Be aware of Lambda concurrency limits and ensure thread safety or use connection pooling.

Comment: The above looks like a response from ChatGPT. Could you please confirm that it is written from your own experience?

Comment: Same comment John? I answered you in a previous question.

Comment: In your comments on the second version, pros, second bullet - it doesn't speed up Cold starts.  Cold starts will always take the same time.  In the event of a Warm start (the calls got to reuse the loaded instance - so no Cold start performed), there is no Cold start at all.

Comment: @ChristianLoris that was meant to be on the first version not the second. If you place it inside the handler, it will be opening the connection at each function execution, but technically it will make cold start faster since it is not part of the cold start. Great catch, thanks.